# Creating table header on top of table header dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

In [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/eQ8rz/), I am creating number of Decoder outputs (D1,D2,D3...) depending on Decoder Type (4x1, 8x1, 16x) in the truth table.

If the Decoder Type is 4x1 I create 4x outputs `4*(D0,D1,D2,D3)` for 4 different Decoders.

If the Decoder Type is 8x1 I create 2x outputs `2*(D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7)` for 2 different Decoders.

If the Decoder Type is 16x1 I create 1x outputs `1*(D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,...,D15)` for 1 Decoder.

Now to make it easy for the user to distinguish between the various decoders, I would like to put the decoder name ontop of the corresponding Decoderoutputs. For example When I have 4x1 decoders, how can I put headers `Decoder1, Decoder2, Decoder3, Decoder4` on top of `(D0,D1,D2,D3)(D0,D1,D2,D3)(D0,D1,D2,D3)(D0,D1,D2,D3)`?

P.S. In the code you can change the decodertype to `8x1 or 16x1`. It's defined as follows:

```
var decoderType="4x1";
```

Comment: not sure if i understand the question correctly..are you just asking to change the headers from "Dx" to "Decoderx"?

Comment: @ ltiong_sh I am asking for putting new Headers Decoder1 on top of the first (D0,D1,D2,D3) and Decoder 2 on top of the second (D0,D1,D2,D3) and Decoder 3 on top of the third (D0,D1,D2,D3) and Decoder 4 on top of the last (D0,D1,D2,D3) in case of "4x1" decoers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use `colspan` property of `td` tag. You should add the following code to `generateTruthTableHTML` function:

```
text += "<th class='th' colspan="+VariableCount+">Variable</td>";
for(var k = 0; k < counter; k++) {
  var count = Math.pow(2,VariableNames.length) /counter;
  text += "<th class='th' colspan=" + count + ">Decoder&nbsp;" +
          (k+1) + "</th>";
}    
text += "</tr><tr>";
```

[Edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/riateche/eQ8rz/3/)

Comment: @ Riateche: exxxcellent I would have kissed your hand, if I were near you ;) thank you